# "Unable to load Author information" in Xcode

Tags: xcode

New to Xcode and a weird block is up on the screen that I cannot get rid of. Anyone familiar?

[image: The vertical box to the right of the code that says, "Unable to load author information"]

Answer (score 3):

Unselect Authors from the top-right menu or you can use the shortcut: ⌃⇧⌘A

[image: Unselect Authors from top right menu]

Comment: Correct, but more context would improve this answer. The Authors view shows who wrote each group of lines in the file, according to the version control system. If the file isn’t part of a repository, there won’t be any author info to show.